# Unable to reflect databases in flask sqlalchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am attempting to use flask-sqlalchemy(flask version 0.10, flask-sqlalch version 1.0, python 3.3.3) to reflect a table in my database and am running into an error. when i use the code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://**appropriate connection string here **'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

db.reflect(app = app)
```

get the following error:

```
file "testmodel.py", line 9, in (module)
db.reflect(app = app)
File "~pathToSqlAlch\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 872, in reflect
self.execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'reflect')
File "~pathToSqlAlch\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 848, in _execute_for_all_tables
op(bind=self.get_engine(app,bind), tables=tables)
reflect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tables'
```

any idea what could cause this or what i may be doing wrong?

Comment: Post the full traceback.

Comment: i updated commend with full traceback. When i had googled the error previously i got saw an issue in github for flask-sqlalchemy for similar stuff, but it stated it was fixed... i assume the latest version available from pip/pypi (1.0) had the fix, but maybe this isnt the case? I am not familiar enough yet with the flask/sqlalchemy and the differences between python 2/3 to really understand the cause of the issue.

Comment: Did you type the stack trace? Is "refelct" a typo?

Comment: i did type it, i corrected the typo. it is spelled correctly in my code (or id probably get an different, easier error from the python interpreter:) )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that this [has been broken for awhile](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/issues/53), even into Flask-SQLAlchemy version 1.0.

Version 1.0 was released with [this commit](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/commit/b242d414b671ffa521dbb3e1c3452b53c34366f9) on July 17th, 2013. The issue was only closed a few weeks later (as a result of [this commit](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/commit/1968a92ec79a80f2c53c133d874be7d6f53f64c0) on July 31st, 2013).

So, you're not alone: it's a bug. The fix has not yet been released in a stable version.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the answer. I wasn't sure of the exact timeline of the fix vs the release date of the current stable version. Now the question is do i skip flask-sqlalchemy for now and try to use regular sqlalchemy for my purposes(in which i assume reflection works.) I am somewhat unsure of how to install a non stable version of flask-sqlalchemy, though im sure some googling would find me the answer. I am not using either at the moment, but sqlAlchemy seems to have some useful functionality.

Answer (score 1):

What I did to fix my problem was to simply get the current master with pip:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy.git
```